# How to use mousePressedOver in P5 for phone?

Tags: javascript, web, mobile, p5.js, mobile-website

I am making a virtual open when website with the P5 library. I have to make it compatible with phones.I have added the invisibility feature to test it. I know how to add one-touch but how do I multiple touches as this requires multiple touches?
Here is my code

```
var laugh, laughI, sadI, sad, titleI, title, annoyI, annoy, motiI, moti
var stressI, stress, angryI, angry;


function preload(){

    laughI  = loadImage("images/laugh.png");
    sadI    = loadImage("images/sad.png");
    titleI  = loadImage("images/title.png");
    annoyI  = loadImage("images/annoy.png");
    motiI   = loadImage("images/motivation.png");
    stressI = loadImage("images/stress.png");
    angryI  = loadImage("images/angry.png");

}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, 1800);

    title = createSprite(windowWidth/2, 80)
    title.addImage(titleI)
    title.scale = 0.9;

    laugh = createSprite(windowWidth/2, 270);
    laugh.addImage(laughI);
    laugh.scale = 0.2;

    sad = createSprite(windowWidth/2, 550);
    sad.addImage(sadI);
    sad.scale = 0.2;

    annoy = createSprite(windowWidth/2, 830);
    annoy.addImage(annoyI);
    annoy.scale = 0.2;

    moti = createSprite(windowWidth/2, 1110);
    moti.addImage(motiI);
    moti.scale = 0.2;

    stress = createSprite(windowWidth/2, 1390);
    stress.addImage(stressI);
    stress.scale = 0.2;

    angry = createSprite(windowWidth/2, 1670);
    angry.addImage(angryI);
    angry.scale = 0.2;
    
}


function draw() {
    background(0);

    if(mouseIsPressed){ 
     laugh.visible = false;
    }

      
   drawSprites();
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a phone I believe you will get the `mousePressed()` event if a user taps, and `mouseIsPressed` should be set to true when a touch happens (at least until the number of touches decreases). However you can also explicitly check for touches with the [`touches`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/touches) array.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  // Prevent top level gesture scrolling/zooming
  // This if iOS Safari specific
  document.addEventListener("gesturestart", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
}

let pressedAt;
let clickedAt;

function mousePressed(e) {
  pressedAt = frameCount;
}

function mouseClicked(e) {
  clickedAt = frameCount;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  if (frameCount - clickedAt < 30) {
    background("orange");
  } else if (frameCount - pressedAt < 30) {
    background("blue");
  } else {
    if (touches.length) {
      background("green");
      text(`${mouseIsPressed ? 'mouse pressed' : 'mouse not pressed'} (touches: ${touches.length})`, 10, height / 2);
    } else if (mouseIsPressed) {
      background("red");
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Since snippets don't work on mobile, you can run the example here: https://editor.p5js.org/Kumu-Paul/full/LpkV7Gio2